# Threading: allow one thread to access data while blocking others, and then stop blocked threads from executing the same code

Tags: c#, multithreading

imagine the simplest DB access code with some in-memory caching -

```
if exists in cache  
    return object  
else  
    get from DB  
    add to cache  
    return object
```

Now, if the DB access takes a second and I have, say, 5 ASP.Net requests/threads hitting that same code within that second, how can I ensure only the first one does the DB call?  I have a simple thread lock around it, but that simply queues them up in an orderly fashion, allowing each to call the DB in turn.  My data repositories basically read in entire tables in one go, so we're not talking about Get by Id data requests.

Any ideas on how I can do this?  Thread wait handles sound almost what I'm after but I can't figure out how to code it.

Surely this must be a common scenario?

Existing pseudocode:

```
lock (threadLock)  
{  
    get collection of entities using Fluent NHib  
    add collection to cache  
}
```

Thanks,
Col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question. The "lock()" is fine, it prevents the other threads proceeding into that code while any other thread is in there. Then, inside the lock perform your first pseudo-code. Check if it's cached already, if not, retrieve the value and cache it. The next thread will then come in, check the cache, find it's available and use that.

Comment: thanks Roger. I've thought of that, but it's slightly more complicated in that I have also got a background cache refresh mechanism running which will pre-emptively refresh it. Hence if I were to check if it's in cache, when hit by the background cache-refresh thread, it will always appear to be in cache. Yes, I could add a boolean forceRefresh parameter (and I've already tried that) but it seems messy...

Comment: If you want to get more complex you can use more advanced synchronisation objects such as a Mutex, which would allow only one thing to own the mutex at a time and allow you to control access to variables. You want to ensure that you hold locks for as short a time as possible as depending on how you implemented it the background refresh thread could block access to cached values. You could always have logic like, 1) Is in cache? If yes, get from cache, else 2) Lock, and check cache again to see if someone just put it there since last check, then either grab from cache or retrieve.

Comment: Sorry, didn't properly read your scenario in your last comment. Yeah, you could use a "forceRefresh" flag if you want to skip cache checks in this code if the background thread needs to force update it, or you could just do the lock(threadLock) (which is very much like using the Mutex anyway) in a different function specifically to update the cache.

Comment: What are you going to lock as "threadLock"? The whole instance? -> Poor design. Use a semaphore...

Comment: thanks Roger, Jaster, Joe and 9dan for your replies, and apologies for the slow reply. I ended up going with my original solution with the conditional re-checking of cache OR forceRefresh before performing the DB access. I had 2 or 3 other related bugs which I've now traced down, and they were the cause of my initial confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Surely this must be a common scenario?

Not necessarily as common as you may think.

In many similar caching scenarios:

- the race condition you describe doesn't happen frequently (it requires multiple requests to arrive when the cache is cold)
- the data returned from the database is readonly, and data returned by multiple requests is essentially interchangeable.
- the cost of retrieving the database is not so prohibitive that it matters.

But if in scenario you absolutely need to prevent this race condition, then use a lock as suggested by Roger Perkins.

Comment: Well, explicit locking will be better. Otherwise you can easily saturate DB I/O at the prime time, effectively disabling whole web application at the moment. The cost of locking is not at all prohibitive, because as pointed this answer, it will not happen frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Monitor/Mutext over lock. Using lock u need to specify a resource (may also use this-pointer, which is not recommended).
try the following instead:

```
Mutext myMutex = new Mutex();
// if u want it systemwide use a named mutex
// Mutext myMutex = new Mutex("SomeUniqueName");

mutex.WaitOne();
// or 
//if(mutex.WaitOne(<ms>))
//{
// //thread has access
//} 
//else 
//{
// //thread has no access
//}
<INSERT CODE HERE>

mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

Comment: But you've also just created a new resource to do this (you could easily just create something of type "object" to use lock and you'll have a robust critical section - this isn't really the place to argue the difference between a Mutex and a Critical Section either). At least using lock() will take care of any exceptions thrown inside the lock (and automatically release it) where you'll need to be careful to handle it properly when doing it manually.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know general solution or established algorithm is exist.

I personally use below code pattern to solve problem like this.

1) Define a integer variable that can be accessed by all thread.

```
int accessTicket = 0;
```

2) Modify code block

```
int myTicket = accessTicket;

lock (threadLock)
{
    if (myTicket == accessTicket)
    {
        ++accessTicket;
        //get collection of entities using Fluent NHib
        //add collection to cache
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Purpose of this code is not prevent multiple DB access of duplicate caching. We can do it with normal thread lock.

By using the access ticket like this we can prevent other thread doing again already finished work.

**UPDATE#2**

### LOOK THERE IS `lock (threadLock)`

Look before comment.

Look carefully before vote down.

Comment: That code caches something only the very first time, not for different queries of different values. It's also not very thread safe when accessing the variable "accessTicket" as something could do "int myTicket = accessTicket" just after the value has been increased below and would therefore run the DB access itself.

Comment: @Roger I think, read access to the accessTicket is thread safe. Isn't it?

Comment: @Roger I did't deleted lock, lock is there as first. Why your lock only method is thread safe and my lock + accessTicket method is unsafe?

Comment: this is mainly answer to the OP's question "how can I ensure only the first one does the DB call"

Comment: @9dan Your writing to the value of accessTicket inside the lock(), you can't control when the other threads get to see that written value changed (it can happen at many different times depending on it happening on the same CPU core of different cores, etc). Your also trying to make sure the first ever call of this code goes to the DB, not the first ever call of a certain item in the DB. What happens when they query a different value?

Comment: @9dan Specifically to your updated answer, Thread A comes along, gets value of accessTicket, proceeds to increment value of accessTicket then do work. Just after ++accessTicket happens on Thread A, Thread B runs the code, gets the increased value of accessTicket and then sits on the lock(). When it finally gets into the lock, myTicket does indeed equal accessTicket again and so performs the query a 2nd time.

Comment: @Roger I think you don't understand the logic of this code. Basically, normal execution is the same with or without accessTicket. When two or more thread of execution arrive this critical section, those thread always enter and execute the critical section code. But with accessTicket check only one thread execute and the other do nothing. That's the difference.

Comment: @Roger quote "Thread A comes along .... query a 2nd time." This is very normal execution of multi threads. Your lock only version execute like this. Isn't it?

Comment: @9dan Your code only stops two threads being in the "lock" at the same time. You do "int myTicket = accessTicket" outside the lock, therefore a 2nd thread can do that at any time (including just after ++accessTicket). Then, myTicket will still equal accessTicket when this 2nd thread finally gets into the lock.

Comment: @9dan You assume both threads hit the lock at exactly the same time and therefore have the same value of myTicket. If the 2nd thread is slightly behind then it can get the updated value of accessTicket before it hits the lock.

Comment: @Roge "Your code only stops two threads being in the "lock" at the same time" That's Right! I intended to that! This could be vast advantage over normal thread lock, and I personally experienced lots of performance gain.

Comment: @Roger "... If the 2nd thread is slightly behind then it can get the updated value of accessTicket before it hits the lock." Again Normal Execution of Multi Thread!!

Comment: @9dan Seriously. It's not thread safe. Assume the DB query takes 5 seconds. That's 5 seconds from the point of incrementing accessTicket that any other thread that comes along will get the updated value and therefore pass the "myTicket == accessTicket" check. You query the value "outside" the lock(). It can be done by any other thread at "any" other time, even while the other thread is doing the DB query.

Comment: @Roger Please think over what difference accessTicket make. You are almost spamming same words again and again.

Comment: @9dan Someone else please jump in and tell me I'm wrong? accessTicket stops a 2nd thread doing the work again "only" if it comes through at virtually the same time as the thread that ends up doing the work (and is assigned the same value for myTicket). At any other time we process this code, accessTicket has a bigger value, so myTicket does too, so the check passes and we query the DB again. I don't know how many ways to say it.

Comment: @Roger I'll tell you again. With or without the accessTicket normal multi thread execution is the same. And read access of the acccessTicket is thread safe. Therefore this is thread safe indeed.

Comment: come on... Threading with "lock flags"? Is this your first application? Its like using polling as an event stratagy. There is no need to discuss this, its just wrong. Either use a semaphore or stay away from threads!

Comment: @Jaster you are misreading too. did you see `lock (threadLock)` ??

Comment: Seems to me like the increment to `accessTicket` should be after the query instead of before, because the other threads are much more likely to hit this code during the first thread's query than in the instant between the first thread taking the lock and incrementing `accessTicket`.

Comment: @Justin before or after is not an issue. increment happens inside of the critical section.

Comment: @9dan Yes, but `accessTicket` is not fully protected by the critical section, because it is read before the lock statement.  This means that any invariants or definitions about the purpose of `accessTicket` are not necessarily valid.  What do you want `accessTicket` to mean, anyway?  Is it the number of queries that have completed, or the number of queries that have started?  It doesn't consistently mean either now.  It's only okay to break the invariant during a critical section, and then only if there is no way to see the value outside of the critical section.

Comment: @Justin accessTicket means, if two or more thread arrives at the critical section in a very small time window let the first thread execute and avoid all other thread's execution (best case) or effect nothing (worst case). If you curios enough, test by yourself this scheme. I personally used this pattern YEARS.

Comment: @Justin What do you mean by invariant? The accessTicket must not be accessed equally or evenly. Its a kind of tie breaker. One get, others don't get. If you can carefully design more advanced scheme you could totally serialize multi thread access at the same time selectively allow only some of thread execute and other pass through.

Comment: @9dan Consider this case:
**Thread1:** Thread1.myTicket = 0. Take threadLock. Does Thread1.myTicket == accessTicket? Yes. Set accessTicket = 1. Start slow DB query.
**Thread2:** Thread2.myTicket = 1. Check threadLock. Wait.
**Thread1:** DB query completes. Release threadLock and continue.
**Thread2:** Finished waiting on threadLock. Take threadLock. Does Thread2.myTicket == accessTicket? 1==1? Yes. Set accessTicket = 2. Start DB query (*DUPLICATE*)!

Comment: @Justin Ok, you are right. Increasing accessTicket AFTER the operation would give more performance gain than the BEFORE version, but BEFORE version still do more job than NOTHING. Isn't it?

Comment: @9dan I don't think it would give much performance gain. You'd have to profile it to be sure, I guess.

Comment: @Justin I intended to reduce "Start DB query (DUPLICATE)!" thing in the first place. No answerers cared about this. End result is all the nonsense comments and down votes. Ridiculous.